# Local MYSQL won't start OS X 10.9.3

Tags: mysql, installation

I have downloaded MYSQL via:

```
bash <(curl -Ls http://git.io/eUx7rg)
```

Prior to installing I've completely uninstalled previous components via:

```
http://community.jaspersoft.com/wiki/uninstall-mysql-mac-os-x
```

I've had to modify permissions in order to see the log file and see primarily permissions errors. Also, when I try:

```
type mysql
```

The result, in terminal, points to a directory that does not exist on my local system. When I trace the path to the executable (via Finder) I get the following error in Terminal:

```
/usr/local/mysql-5.6.19-osx10.7-x86_64/bin/mysql ; exit;
ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/mysql/mysql.sock' (2)
logout
```

Also, when I look at my.conf file, everything is asterisked out:

```
# For advice on how to change settings please see
# http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/server-configuration-defaults.html

[mysqld]

# Remove leading # and set to the amount of RAM for the most important data
# cache in MySQL. Start at 70% of total RAM for dedicated server, else 10%.
# innodb_buffer_pool_size = 128M

# Remove leading # to turn on a very important data integrity option: logging
# changes to the binary log between backups.
# log_bin

# These are commonly set, remove the # and set as required.
# basedir = .....
# datadir = .....
# port = .....
# server_id = .....
# socket = .....

# Remove leading # to set options mainly useful for reporting servers.
# The server defaults are faster for transactions and fast SELECTs.
# Adjust sizes as needed, experiment to find the optimal values.
# join_buffer_size = 128M
# sort_buffer_size = 2M
# read_rnd_buffer_size = 2M 

sql_mode=NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION,STRICT_TRANS_TABLES
```

Comment: Had the same problem. Had to switch machines for a week and installing MySQL on "OS X 10.9.3 (13D65)" would not work. Had to wipe the account clean and reinitialize the user to get it going. Apparently there was still an old mysql which wasn't uninstalled completely. Google "uninstall mysql manually".

Comment: Uninstalled, reinstalled and restarted the machine. I now have mysql running but get an "access denied" error when trying to login via SqlPro. Feel free to post this as an answer so I can give you credit:) Also - my new error: MySQL said: Access denied for user 'root'@'127.0.0.1' (using password: YES)

Answer (score 0):

Had the same problem. Had to switch machines for a week and installing MySQL on "OS X 10.9.3 (13D65)" would not work. Had to wipe the account clean and reinitialize the user to get it going. Apparently there was still an old mysql which wasn't uninstalled completely. Google "uninstall mysql manually"

The access denied happens sometime when the grant is given to the interface 127.0.0.1 but not to localhost.

Try granting access to %, 127.0.0.1, and localhost.